# Angular $resource.save to json file does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

hope to get some help ;)

the following code does not make .json file with new data info.
I suspect it is a stupid mistake 
I have permissions for the data/artist folder

```js
'use strict';

musicApp.factory('artistData', function($resource) {

var resource = $resource('/data/artist/:id', { id: '@id' });

return {
    getArtist: function(id) {
        return resource.get({id: id});
    },
    saveArtist: function(artist) {
         if (!artist.id) {
             resource.query().$promise.then(function(data) {
                artist.id = data.length + 1;
                 resource.save(artist);
            });
        }
         else {
            resource.save(artist);
         }
    },
    getAllArtists: function() {
        return resource.query();
    }
}


})
```

The form is `$valid` but I have in Console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 501 (Not Implemented)

Comment: `.save` must be `.$save`

Comment: ok but still nothing ...

Comment: u get 501 for get or for post request? Please show us something, otherwise it'll be super hard to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: guess resource.query({id: artist.id}) will solve the problem, but it's just a guess.

Comment: In your `saveArtist` function you do something pretty scary: your code lets the client decide what the ID should be for a new object. Typically your server should be the one assigning new ID's. Your current approach will fail when there is more than one user in your system. To resolve the console error, look at the network tab and see what the HTTP request is that generates the error. As is, we can't tell you why your server returns a 501  for that query.

Comment: Thank you guys i've fix 501 in the web-server.js file :

function main(argv) {
    new HttpServer({
        'GET':createServlet(StaticServlet),
        'POST':createServlet(StaticServlet),
        'HEAD':createServlet(StaticServlet)
    }).start(Number(process.env.PORT || DEFAULT_PORT));      but still can not create new json file

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add this in web-server.js

```js
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
         if (self.attemptingToAccessOutsideLocalAppPath(parts)) {
             return self.sendForbidden_(req, res, path);
         }

         return self.writeFile_(req, res, path);
     }
```

Now works fine and adds new json files in data/artist